# Not show add bluetooth device dialog

Tags: bluetooth, windows-10-v1703

I tried many steps with google but still cannot find the solution...
When I click on [Add Bluetooth & Other devices] not show as below image?
Windows 10 Pro - 1703

[image: Thanks]

Comment: look in eventlog if you see error message

Comment: Activation of app Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy!App failed with error: This app can't be activated by the Built-in Administrator. See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

Comment: "Built-in Administrator" looks like you use the admin without UAC. is this true? all those GUI settings are apps and normally need UAC turned on.

Comment: UAC set as normal. just found the solution because i used local account that's why cannot run Universal Apps. below is how to enable local account to run Metro Apps. anyway thanks for your idea.
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-an-administrator-to-open-metro-apps-in-windows-10/

Comment: you disabled UAC for admin type and so the UI is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Changed [Admin Approval Mode For Built-in Administrator Account: Enabled]

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-an-administrator-to-open-metro-apps-in-windows-10/